# Nuxtjs server side rendering could not call to the api behind cloudflare

Tags: node.js, axios, nuxt.js, cloudflare

We are building a project with NuxtJS. The API is deployed on AWS and used Cloudflare to set up DNS.
Sending the request to asyncData(), inside this method we made the call to API via domain(the domain pointed to actual load balancer URL of AWS - by setting up CNAME in Cloudflare). The error 503 was returned. Looks like the call is occurring inside of nodejs server. If anyone was familiar with this situation, please give me a hand. Thanks in advance.

Also noticed that, this is not appearing when calling the API with nuxtjs from the browser. As I understand, nuxtjs's asyncData is executed from the server, while on navigation it executed from browser.

Comment: What if you try to reach the API from a regular Node.js environment? Is it blocked too?

Comment: Not try it yet. You mean the problem when we call the API from nodejs server.

Comment: Let me create a regular nodejs environment and call the api.